# Large horizontal table inside a bootstrap grid column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large table inside a bootstrap grid column.

I want the page to **have a horizontal scrollbar** (not make the parent element scrollable) and I want other elements of page (like header) to grow horizontally with it.

Check out my sample below.

**1st problem:** header is not growing in width to fit the page's width.

**2nd problem:** `.outer-main-border` is not growing properly and `.inner-data-table` overflows it. I don't want this to happen.

**Update 1:** I know how to use `overflow-x:scroll` on the parent element. Don't want to make that scrollable! This page has more content below this section and I must make the whole page scrollable not just this part.

**Update 2:** The main problem is, bootstrap row is not growing as much as the children inside it and I want a pure Css solution to fix this.

**Update 3:** it Looks like, a single column bootstrap grid, works fine, but with more than one column, it just calculates the width of the last column and the first column is not taken into account.

```css
        .outer-main-border {
            border: 2px solid red;
            display: inline-block;
            min-width:100%;
        }
        .inner-data-table{
            white-space: nowrap;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: 5px;
        }
            .inner-data-table td {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                padding: 2px;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Application</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="outer-main-border">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">Some Content Here</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">

                        <table class="inner-data-table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                                <td>Sample Content</td>
                                <td>Some Text</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think give your `.outer-main-border {width:100%;  overflow-x: auto;}` is better than scroll all page

Comment: @Duannx this is just a sample, in my real application my page needs to have scroll, not an elemnt.

Comment: @AfshinGh Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v6rja1dz/1/)

Comment: @user3284463: This is gonna be my last resort. I prefer a pure Css solution, but if I couldn't find any, I'll go with JS.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out if data table helps you. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

cheers.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want the page to be scrollable not the parent element.